# ActiveMQ Camel messages

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am trying to deploy app using activemq and camel, when i am strating my tomcat server I am getting all suspicious messages on console, even when there are no messages in the queue on tye broker , the error messages are

```
09:56:27.769 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG o.a.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer - remove: ID:LT-HP-2012907-53495-1360230974137-0:7:1:5, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0
09:56:27.769 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:LT-HP-xxxxxxxxxx-0:7:1 Transaction Commit :null
09:56:27.769 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:LT-HP-xxxxxxxx:1 Transaction Rollback
09:56:27.770 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG o.a.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer - remove: ID:LT-HP-2012907-53495-1360230974137-0:6:1:5, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0
09:56:27.770 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:LT-HP-xxxxxxxxx:6:1 Transaction Commit :null
09:56:27.770 [Camel (eventProcessorCamelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[events]] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:LT-HP-xxxxxxxxx:6:1 Transaction Rollback
```

Transaction Commit :null Transaction Rollback *****As you can see in the debug message, there are no messages on the queue, still I am getting debug message as Transaction commit:null and Transaction Rollback. Is it expected? Why ActiveMQ is trying to commit null when there are no messages 
Is this expecetd or am i doing anything wrong

Comment: This is a duplicate question of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748285/camel-active-mq-suspicious-error-messages

Comment: You should NOT duplicate your questions! This is not good behavior showing to the community!

Answer (score 1):

Thats verbose logging.

Camel is using Spring DMLC when reading messages transactional from ActiveMQ.

What's essentially is done is something like this (psuedo code, over simplified):

```
begin transaction()
receive()
.. handle message 
commit()
```

Turn off debug logging if this bothers you.

Comment: so even there are no messages , camel with DMLC begin transaction and commits?

Comment: if you have session transactions, yes. Camel needs to start a transaction before reading - and knowing if there is a message on the queue or not - then committing